# Find an anchor in a Div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, find

In javascript I have a reference to a div. In that div is an anchor element with a name='**foundItem**'

How do I get a reference to the anchor with the name **foundItem** which is in the Div I have the reference of?

There are 'many' **foundItem** anchors in other divs on the page. I need 'this' DIVs one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery, it's dead easy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){    
    var item = $("#yourDivId a[name=foundItem]")
)};
</script>
```

Update:

As per the comments, if you have control over what to id/name/class your anchor tag/s, it would be best to apply a class to them:

```
<div id="firstDiv">
    <a href="someurl.htm" class="foundItem">test</a>
</div>
<div id="secondDiv">
    <a href="someOtherUrl.htm" class="foundItem">test another one</a>
</div>
<!-- and so forth -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){    
    var item = $("#firstDiv a.foundItem");
    alert(item.html()); // Will result in "test"

    var item2 = $("#secondDiv a.foundItem");
    alert(item2.html()); // Will show "test another one"

)};
</script>
```

If you're doing anything with javascript, jQuery saves you tons of time and is worth investing the effort to learn well. Start with http://api.jquery.com/browser/ to get an intro to what's possible.

Comment: so if I changed the anchor to an id of foundItem and used jQuery I could use:

var item = $("#yourDivId a.foundItem");

yes?

Comment: Yes, or you could just use `$('foundItem')`, or without jquery just use `document.getElementById('foundItem')`

Comment: Yes, but as Rob says, at that point you would just get by the Id directly. Having said that, you don't want more than one element with the same Id (or name for that matter. If you have control over what to do with your anchor tag, then just apply a class to it...as the commenting syntax is limited, I'll edit the answer above.

Comment: Oh - just noticed you used the class designation in var item = $("#yourDivId a.foundItem"); 
That wouldn't work if you change the ID. You'd want var item = $("#yourDivId a#foundItem");

Comment: Thanks ovalsquare, that worked great. I am now officially stunned by jQuery. wow....

Comment: If the only thing you're scripting is this one behavior, use of jQuery may be overkill. While it's a terrific library, it is unnecessary for this task, and the bare-DOM method is widely supported and available without dependencies of any kind.

Answer (score 5):

```
// assuming you're not using jquery or mootools 
// assume div is mydiv
var lst = mydiv.getElementsByTagName('a');
var myanchor;
for(var i=0; i<lst.length; ++i) {
    if(lst[i].name && lst[i].name == 'foundItem') {
        myanchor = lst[i];
        break;
    }
}


// the mootools method
var myanchor = $(mydiv).getElement('a[name=foundItem]');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the getElementsByTagName method to get the anchor elements in the div, then look for the one with the correct name attribute:

```
var found = null;
var e = divReference.getElementsByTagName('A');
for (var i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
  if (e[i].name && e[i].name == 'foundItem') {
    found = e[i];
    break;
  }
}
```

If `found` is not null, you got the element.

If you happen to use the jQuery library, you can let it do the searching:

```
var found = null;
var e = $(divReference).find('a[name=foundItem]');
if (e.length == 1) found = e.get(0);
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Although other posters are correct that jQuery (and other libs) make tasks like these simple, it's wrong to assume the author is willing to use jQuery if s/he hasn't stated it -- especially when this may be the only scripting need. jQuery is a kitchen sink. It would be different if the OP made it sound like there were robust scripting needs, but for something this simple reliance on jQuery is lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and save yourself time.

```
var theAnchor = $('#divId a[name=foundItem]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but wanted a function to handle the load of a page dynamically and scroll to the anchor of choice.

```
function scrollToAnchor(anchor_val) {

  alert("" + anchor_val);

  var page = document.getElementById('tables');
  var found = null;
  var cnt = 0;
  var e = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {

    if (e[i].name && e[i].name == anchor_val) {

      found = e[i];

      break;

    }

    cnt++;

  }

  if (found) {

    var nPos = found.offsetTop;

    alert("" + nPos);

    page.scrollBy(0, nPos);

  } else {

    alert('Failed with call of scrollToAnchor()' + cnt);

  }

}
```